# how to support android devices that have the same dpis but have different resolutions

Tags: android, screen, resolution

HI guys i could really use the help on this one

I have an app/game that i have compiled into 7 apks for all different screen sizes i cant use the same apk since the file size will end up being to large.

So far i have been able to use the  to reach my desired resolution with one exception

screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="large"

this returns me a resolution of 800 by 1280s and also the 1200 by 1920s i need to be able to use 2 different tags one that will give me the 800 by 1280s that its supporting and one that will give me the 1200 by 1920s

here is the list i get when only useing this tag
 Nexus 7– flo 
Nexus 7– deb

KOBO
 Arc 7HD– cardhu

LGE
 VU3– vu3 LG G Pad 8.3– awifi

SHARP
 AQUOS PAD SH-08E– SH-08E

SAMSUNG
 Galaxy Note– SGH-I717D GT-N7000B– GT-N7000B 
Galaxy Note– SGH-I717M 
Galaxy Note– SHV-E160K 
Galaxy Note– SGH-I717 
Galaxy Note– SHV-E160L 
Galaxy Note– GT-N7000 
Galaxy Note– GT-I9220 
Galaxy Note– GT-I9228 
Galaxy Note– SHV-E160S 
Galaxy Note– SGH-I717R 
Galaxy Note– SC-05D 
Galaxy Note– SCH-i889

SONY ERICSSON
 Xperia Z Ultra– C6802

is there a way to take the 800 by 1280s that show up here and move them over into one apk and the 1200 by 1920s and put them into a different one?

to sum it up in the easiest way possible i need to support same dpis with different resolutions